# Get php fetch array values from json encode jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

this is the code i have, actually i am inserting a array in json encode data and getting back via jquery.

```
        $list_type_query = "select * from assettype";
        //the asset type table contains (id & type) column 
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $list_type_query);
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            $result_value = array("Status" => "haslist", "list" => $r);
        }
```

this is jquery side.

```
        case "loaddefaultmodel":                       
        var showtype = $('#sh');                       
        var showvalue = '<span>'+data['list']+'</span>';
        showtype.html(showvalue);
        break;
```

$('#sh') is a div i need to show all type content in the span inside the div.

if i use the **data['list'][0]['type']**  i getting a object 0 value.

how to show all value one by one dynamically in div.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue in your php code.
Because in every loop, the $r just get every current index data, And $result_value just get current index data.

You can try this...

```
    $list_type_query = "select * from assettype";
    //the asset type table contains (id & type) column 
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $list_type_query);
    $all_data = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $all_data[] = $r;
    }
    $result_value = array("Status" => "haslist", "list" => $all_data);
```

Comment: i geeting the result in array like Object {Status: "haslist", list: Array[6]}

Comment: and in list array list: Array[6]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object

Comment: i need how to show all the object data in div in auto without giving any object manually.